# How to split a list (matrix) into other lists?

Tags: python, list, matrix, arraylist, split

I don't know how to convert a matrix of `10x10` into four matrices of `5x5`, for example:

```
[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], # matrix 10x10
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
 [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
 [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]
```

I need to convert into this:

```
[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14] # 4 like this with the other numbers too
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24] 
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
 [50, 51, 52, 53, 54]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to split matrix into 4 quadrants in python using numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855180/how-to-split-matrix-into-4-quadrants-in-python-using-numpy) and [how to split a matrix into 4 blocks using numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105375/how-to-split-a-matrix-into-4-blocks-using-numpy)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> matrix = \
... [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
...  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
...  [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
...  [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
...  [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
...  [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
...  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
...  [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
...  [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
...  [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([x[:5] for x in matrix[:5]])
[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
 [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
 [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
 [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
 [50, 51, 52, 53, 54]]
>>>
```

`sequence[:5]` gets the first five items in `sequence`.  So, `matrix[:5]` gets the first five sublists in `matrix` and `x[:5]` gets the first five items in each of those sublists.  `pprint.pprint` is only used to format the output.